# How can I send an email to a user using Java?

Tags: java, email

I am using this code to send emails to users

```
static void SendEmail(String email) 
{
    System.out.println(email);
      String recipient = email;
      String sender = "*my email*";
      String host = "127.0.0.1";
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
      try 
      {
          MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
          message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
          message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));
         message.setSubject("Vote Results");
         message.setText("Votes have ended, here are the results: Apple:" + votes1 + " Banana:" + votes2);
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      } 
      catch (MessagingException e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

but it keeps returning this exception:

> com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host,
> port: 127.0.0.1, 25; timeout -1;   nested exception is:

Comment: Do you have a mail server running on 127.0.0.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not an SMTP server, and you cannot send emails directly. You could try adding Google SMTP: it is free but is kind of restrictive. Add something like this to your code:

```
prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Comment: well now the exception is that there is no password specified, where should I add the password to the properties? and the password is for my email right?

Comment: you should instance your session with a PasswordAuthenticator: try to watch this https://netcorecloud.com/tutorials/send-email-in-java-using-gmail-smtp/

Comment: The thing is my project isn't a maven project

Comment: it is not a problem: import the library in another way. maybe you can download the jar